# How to use aggregate() over multiple columns based on condition

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, subset

I would like to use `aggregate` to calculate simple summary metrics over multiple columns, based on certain conditions, e.g. only for those rows that are `> 0`. `subset`ting the data for values `> 0` prior to using `aggregate` obviously won't work, as that will remove the entire row for all columns, even if only one zero occurs. See the following code for illustration:

```
idA <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
idB <- c("C","D","C","D","C","D","C","D","C","D")
colA <- c(0,2,3,0,0,3,9,5,6,1)
colB <- c(9,3,0,2,2,4,6,1,9,9)
colC <- c(0,0,5,7,3,9,8,1,2,3)

df <- data.frame(idA,idB,colA,colB,colC)

aggregate(.~idA+idB,df,FUN=NROW)
```

The `aggregate` command in this form, of course, makes no sense, as all the columns have an equal number of rows.

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
idA  idB  colA  colB  colC
A    C    1     2     2
B    C    2     2     2
A    D    1     2     1
B    D    3     3     3
```

Hence the need for a conditional statement, including only rows `> 0`. Alternatively, I'm sure there is a smart way of doing this via `data.table`. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `aggregate(.~ idA + idB, df , function(x) length(x[x > 0]))`

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll tag it accordingly.

Comment: Someone did already and then deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In data.table, you can do the following:

```
setDT(df)
df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 0)),.(idA,idB), .SDcols = setdiff(names(df), c('idA','idB'))]
```

Comment: I guess `length(x[x > 0])` should be the same as `sum(x > 0)` except if `x` contains NAs, in which case it will include those NAs in the count (which is probably not wanted).